# What data structure is select2 expecting from the server and how should it be handled?

Tags: jquery-select2-4

What data structure is [select2](https://select2.github.io/) (v4.0.3) expecting from the server and how should it be handled?

The question is asked on the official FAQ [here](https://select2.github.io/options.html#what-should-the-results-returned-to-select2-look-like), but there is no answer.

I have tried several variations of data structure, but based on this [tutorial](http://www.southcoastweb.co.uk/jquery-select2-v4-ajaxphp-tutorial) and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcrazyness/XMAq2/), have assumed what should be returned from the server is a list/array of objects/dicts, eg:

```
matches = [{"id":"1", "tag":"Python"},{"id":"2", "tag":"Javascript"},{"id":"3", "tag":"MongoDB"}]
```

I have tried this format with the following Javascript:

```
$("#my_select").select2({
ajax: {
url: "/tag_search",
dataType: 'json',
delay: 250,
data: function (params) {
return {
q: params.term // search term
};
},
processResults: function (data) {
return {
results: data.matches
};
},
cache: true
},
minimumInputLength: 2,
tags: true,
tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
maximumSelectionLength: 5
});
```

Firebug results for search on `Py`:

[image]

The search area just displays this:

[image]

I am expecting all matches to be showing in the dropdown below the search area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

Rename json key (it has to be `text`), so server response is:

```
[{"text": "Python", "id": 1}]
```

(after coming across [this document](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#changed-id)).

I also just returned the list itself from the server, rather than making the list a dict value.

**Javascript**

```
$("#my_select").select2({
ajax: {
url: "/tag_search",
dataType: 'json',
delay: 250,
data: function (params) {
return {
q: params.term // search term
};
},
processResults: function (data) {
return {
results: data
};
},
cache: true
},
minimumInputLength: 2,
tags: true,
tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
maximumSelectionLength: 5
});
```